# Unable to retrieve an updated property of an element of an observable collection

Tags: c#, class, xaml, uwp, observablecollection

I am working on a UWP Election conductor on VS2015. I have made the candidate class and set its properties as follows:

```
public class Candidate
{
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public CandidateSNo S_no { get; set; }
    public CandidateCategoryNo Category_no { get; set; }
}

public enum CandidateCategoryNo
{
    I,
    II,
    III,
    IV,
    V,
    VI
}

public enum CandidateSNo
{
    I,
    II,
    III
}
```

I have made a CandidateManager class to store methods and in it, I have stored an observable collection in a method which contains the 5 properties each of some candidates. Here's the CandidateManager class:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Candidate> getCandidate()
    {
        var _candidate = new ObservableCollection<Candidate>();

        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.I, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "President", Name = "A" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.II, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "President", Name = "B" });
        _candidate.Add(new Candidate() { S_no = CandidateSNo.III, Category_no = CandidateCategoryNo.I, VoteCount = 0, Category = "President", Name = "C" });

        return _candidate;
    }

public static ObservableCollection<Candidate> GetAllCandidates()
            {
                ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = CandidateManager.getCandidate();
                return Candidates;
            }
```

I want the votecount of each candidate to increase by 1 whenever someone selects their names' button. I have made 3 buttons on the page which are for selecting the candidate and a Submit button to submit their choice. After that the result textblock is to show which candidate was selected. Here's the XAML of the mainpage:

> 

```
    <Button Name="Cand2" Width="100" Height="100" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Cand2_Click"/>

    <Button Name="Cand3" Width="100" Height="100" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Cand3_Click"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="50" FontSize="30" Name="Res"/>

    <Button Name="Submit" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Submit" Click="Submit_Click" />

</Grid>
```

And here's the xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates();

        Cand1.Content = CandidateManager.GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.I).Name;
        Cand2.Content = CandidateManager.GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.II).Name;
        Cand3.Content = CandidateManager.GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.III).Name;
    }

    private void Cand1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates();
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand1.Content).FirstOrDefault();
        chosenOne.VoteCount += 1;
        Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand1.Content).FirstOrDefault().VoteCount = chosenOne.VoteCount;
    }

    private void Cand2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates();
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand2.Content).FirstOrDefault();
        chosenOne.VoteCount += 1;
        Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand2.Content).FirstOrDefault().VoteCount = chosenOne.VoteCount;
    }

    private void Cand3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates();
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand3.Content).FirstOrDefault();
        chosenOne.VoteCount += 1;
        Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand3.Content).FirstOrDefault().VoteCount = chosenOne.VoteCount;
    }

    private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates();
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.VoteCount == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (chosenOne != null)
            Res.Text = chosenOne.Name + " -- " + chosenOne.VoteCount.ToString();
        else
            Res.Text = "null";
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that I am unable to retrieve the updated votecount and the result textblock shows null.
This is just a small dummy of the main project, but I'm facing the same problem in the main program. I want to update the votecount and other properties of candidate as the program runs and retrieve them when required. 
Apologies for the long code. Hope you would help.. Thanks !

Comment: You never save the changes to the observablecollection. You fetch an item, then add votes, then forget the item until fetched again. The votes aren't saved.

Comment: ObservableCollection does not notify about a change of a property of its element type. You'll have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your Candidate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use class level variables for observable collection and make changes to same.

Problem with your code is, every method has its own local observable collection instance. I edited few portion of your codebehind, please see

```
   ObservableCollection<Candidate> Candidates = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Candidates = CandidateManager.GetAllCandidates();

        Cand1.Content = CandidateManager.GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.I).Name;
        Cand2.Content = CandidateManager.GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.II).Name;
        Cand3.Content = CandidateManager.GetCandidateByCategoryAndSno(CandidateCategoryNo.I, CandidateSNo.III).Name;
    }

    private void Cand1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand1.Content).FirstOrDefault();
        chosenOne.VoteCount += 1;
        Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand1.Content).FirstOrDefault().VoteCount = chosenOne.VoteCount;
    }

    private void Cand2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand2.Content).FirstOrDefault();
        chosenOne.VoteCount += 1;
        Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand2.Content).FirstOrDefault().VoteCount = chosenOne.VoteCount;
    }

    private void Cand3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand3.Content).FirstOrDefault();
        chosenOne.VoteCount += 1;
        Candidates.Where(c => c.Name == Cand3.Content).FirstOrDefault().VoteCount = chosenOne.VoteCount;
    }

    private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Candidate chosenOne = Candidates.Where(c => c.VoteCount == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (chosenOne != null)
            Res.Text = chosenOne.Name + " -- " + chosenOne.VoteCount.ToString();
        else
            Res.Text = "null";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't quite get that. Where all should I make these three? One on page, one CandidateManager class and the third?

Comment: Thanks it works in the dummy app. But unfortunately not in the main app in which I'm taking input (Name, category. votecount) from the user on one page and displaying output on another. I tried to do this in CandidateManager class's methods too but it requires me to make one observable collection for each method. And there are gonna be 6 pages, so I have to make 6 different observable collections for these too. Can't I just make one and declare it a universal one so that I can access it from anywhere in this app. Thanks!

Comment: If it is working then you should accept this answer as it is satisfying your initial query. About your question, on declaring one observable collection at global level will certainly work but whether you should do that or not is up to your design decision. Technically nothing stop you to do that.

Comment: Where should I declare it then so that it can be accessed universally on the app?

Comment: There are number of ways, simplest way is just create a class file saying "Global.cs" and add your property as public static. Now anywhere under same namespace you can access like 'Global.PropertyName' .